# React server-side rendering AJAX setState() - document is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, reactjs, flux

Without the response from the AJAX request, I will have nothing to display to the user i.e. I store everything in the database.
My component **GenericPage.jsx**:

```
export default class GenericPage extends React.Component {
componentWillMount() {
        if (this.store && this.onStoreUpdated) this.store.addChangeListener(this.onStoreUpdated);
        if (!this.state.page && this.state.pageId) {
            this.fetchData();
        }
    }
onPageStoreUpdated() {
        console.info('onPageStoreUpdated');
        var page = PageStore.getCurrentObject();
        this.setState({page: page, loaded: true}); // the error goes away if I comment this out
    }
    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

My Express JS server code:

```
server.get('*', function (req, res) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        match({routes, location: req.url}, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
            if (error) {
                res.send(500, error.message)
            } else if (redirectLocation) {
                res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
            } else if (renderProps) {
                let htmlStr = React.renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />);
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                res.render('layout', { reactHtml: htmlStr });
            } else {
                console.log('not found')
                res.send(404, 'Not found')
            }
        })
    });
```

Full stack trace:

```
/Users/eric/af/frontend_app/node_modules/react/lib/getActiveElement.js:23
    return document.body;
           ^
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at getActiveElement (/Users/eric/af/frontend_app/node_modules/react/lib/getActiveElement.js:23:12)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.ReactInputSelection.getSelectionInformation (/Users/eric/af/frontend_app/node_modules/react/lib/ReactInputSelection.js:40:23)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.Mixin.initializeAll (/Users/eric/af/frontend_app/node_modules/react/lib/Transaction.js:168:30)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.Mixin.perform (/Users/eric/af/frontend_app/node_modules/react/lib/Transaction.js:133:12)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.Mixin.perform (/Users/eric/af/frontend_app/node_modules/react/lib/Transaction.js:134:20)
    at ReactUpdatesFlushTransaction.assign.perform (/Users/eric/af/frontend_app/node_modules/react/lib/ReactUpdates.js:95:38)
    at Object.flushBatchedUpdates (/Users/eric/af/frontend_app/node_modules/react/lib/ReactUpdates.js:175:19)
    at Object.wrapper [as flushBatchedUpdates] (/Users/eric/af/frontend_app/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:70:21)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.Mixin.closeAll (/Users/eric/af/frontend_app/node_modules/react/lib/Transaction.js:207:25)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.Mixin.perform (/Users/eric/af/frontend_app/node_modules/react/lib/Transaction.js:148:16)
```

I'm using `react` 0.13.3 and `react-router` 1.0.0

Comment: The trick here is to gather your data through promises before loading your application and then hydrate your state from that data. I'm going to shamelessly plug my own implementation here since it's too much code and concept explaining going on to warrant a relevant answer: https://github.com/limelights/react-uniini

Comment: @HenrikAndersson interestingly, that is exactly what I've done the last half an hour, it seems to be working out fine

Comment: Nice. It's the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was not possible to achieve using React component on server side.
So, I moved the AJAX calls to `componentDidMount` in my React components so that they don't affect the server side.
The data that I need to get on the server side, I get them in my server side  Node JS code, outside of any React component, before I render React components:

```
server.get('*', function (req, res) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        match({routes, location: req.url}, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
            if (renderProps) {
                someAsyncHttpRequest(someUrl)
                    .onSuccess((response) => {
                         page = response.body;
                         renderProps.params.page = page;

                         Dispatcher.dispatch({
                              actionType: AppAction.PAGE_FETCHED,
                              data: page
                         });
                    });
                let htmlStr = React.renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />);
                res.render('layout', { reactHtml: htmlStr });
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only load the data in the browser, try moving your `ComponentWillMount` code to `ComponentDidMount`.

Comment: I need the fetch the page from the database and return to the end users, otherwise, there will be nothing for them to see. Technically, I could return those initial data as "hello world" and let the client side script takes care of fetching data. However, users will see a blank page at first. Search engines will probably always see nothing which defeats the purpose of doing React server-side rendering here

Comment: In other words, it is not an option for me

Comment: Makes sense, I misunderstood. You seem to have run into this bug: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5779